# Why is my program running in atom-html-preview and atom-live-server inside Atom but not in Chrome nor in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, atom-editor, web-audio-api

I have a program that uses Web Audio API to visualize the Time Domain waveform of audio. It works fine inside Atom where I use the "atom-html-preview" package by "harmsk", but it doesn't run in Chrome or in JSFiddle.

What is it that I am doing wrong? Is it a syntax error or am I using outdated functions?

EDIT: It also works in "atom-live-server" by "jas-chen"

In Atom, the output looks like [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/ITr9GzwtVtAcoVMuXz/giphy.gif)

```js
let frequencyArray = [];
let analyser;
let request;
var flag=0;
var height=0;

const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const bars = Math.round(canvas.width);
const lineWidth = 3;


var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;


const audio = new Audio();
audio.src =
  "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/storycreator.uploads/ck9kpb5ss0xf90132mgf8z893?client_id=d8976b195733c213f3ead34a2d95d1c1";
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
audio.load();

const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
analyser = context.createAnalyser();
const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);

frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);


  function begin()
  {
    audio.play();
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
  };

  function end()
  {
    cancelAnimationFrame(request);
    audio.pause();
  };

audio.addEventListener("ended", close);

function close()
{
  if(flag==0)
  {
    flag=1;
  }
  else
  {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      flag=0;
  }
}


  const drawCanvas = () => {

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyArray);

      for (var i = 0; i < bars; i+=5) {
       height = frequencyArray[i] * 0.25;

        drawLine(
          {
            i,
            bars,
            height
          },
          canvas,
          ctx
        );
      }

      if(flag==0)
      {
      request = requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
      }
      else
      {
        flag=2;
        close();
      }
  };

  
  const drawLine = (opts, canvas, ctx) => {
    const { i, bars, height } = opts;

    // draw the bar
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#212121";
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY + height);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY - height);
    ctx.stroke();


};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<body>

<button onClick=begin()>Start</button>
<button onClick=end()>End</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle for this to make it easier to examine what's going on?

Comment: @RaymondToy It's there. Try opening the full page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it's because of this error, in the console

> js:47 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.

If you refer to the [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio) in the message, it specifies that

> If you create your AudioContext on page load, you’ll have to call resume() at some time after the user interacted with the page (e.g., user clicked a button). Alternatively, the AudioContext will be resumed after a user gesture if start() is called on any attached node.

Since your `AudioContext` is created before the user gesture (the click), you could modify `begin` function to resume context,

```
  function begin()
  {
    context.resume().then(() => {
          audio.play();
          requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
    });
  };
```

**Working Demo**:

```js
let frequencyArray = [];
let analyser;
let request;
var flag=0;
var height=0;

const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const bars = Math.round(canvas.width);
const lineWidth = 3;


var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;


const audio = new Audio();
audio.src =
  "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/storycreator.uploads/ck9kpb5ss0xf90132mgf8z893?client_id=d8976b195733c213f3ead34a2d95d1c1";
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
audio.load();

const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
analyser = context.createAnalyser();
const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);

frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);


  function begin()
  {
    context.resume().then(() => {
     audio.play();
     requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
    })
  };

  function end()
  {
    cancelAnimationFrame(request);
    audio.pause();
  };

audio.addEventListener("ended", close);

function close()
{
  if(flag==0)
  {
    flag=1;
  }
  else
  {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      flag=0;
  }
}


  const drawCanvas = () => {

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyArray);

      for (var i = 0; i < bars; i+=5) {
       height = frequencyArray[i] * 0.25;

        drawLine(
          {
            i,
            bars,
            height
          },
          canvas,
          ctx
        );
      }

      if(flag==0)
      {
      request = requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
      }
      else
      {
        flag=2;
        close();
      }
  };

  
  const drawLine = (opts, canvas, ctx) => {
    const { i, bars, height } = opts;

    // draw the bar
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#212121";
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY + height);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY - height);
    ctx.stroke();


};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<body>

<button onClick=begin()>Start</button>
<button onClick=end()>End</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>


</body>
</html>
```